# Angular 9 Subscribe inside subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs6

i'm working with Angular 9 and rxjs 6, and i'm trying to get a list of Nodes :

NodeService.ts

`public getList(): Observable<Nodes[]> { return this.http.get<Nodes[]>(URL); }`

Nodes Entity:

```
export class Nodes {
     public id: number;
     public name: string;
     public site_id: number;
     public site: Site;
}
```

nodes.component.ts:

```
public getAllNodes() {
  this.dataSource.data = [];
  this.nodeService.getList()
    .subscribe(
      nodes => {
        nodes.map(
          (node) => {
            this.siteService.getSiteById(node.site_id).subscribe(site => {
              node.site = site;
            })
          });
        this.dataSource.data = nodes;
        console.log(nodes);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
      }
    );
}
```

=> By default, node.site = null, so i use node.site_id to get the complete "Site" object in the subscribe method.
But i have almost 6000 call to "siteService.getSiteById()" and i have error like: Insufficient resources.

Do you have any better way to do it,

Thank you

Comment: That is what switchMap is for..

Comment: If you have to make 6000 calls then its a bad architecture. make your getList return what you need

Comment: It is not a good practice to call APIs in a loop with more items, but you can achieve the same effect by calling one API when selecting any particular node

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make 6000 individual HTTP calls, you might have to modify the backend to return all the info in a single request. Meanwhile, you could try to use RxJS [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) operator with [`concatMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap) with [`from`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/from) and [`of`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of) functions to do the requests sequentially.

```js
import { of, from } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, concatMap, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

public getAllNodes() {
  this.dataSource.data = [];
  let sites = [];
  this.nodeService.getList().pipe(
    switchMap(nodes => {
      let requests = [];
      this.dataSource.data = nodes;
      nodes.forEach(node => requests.push(this.siteService.getSiteById(node.site_id)));
      return from(requests);
    }),
    concatMap(request => of(request)),
    finalize(() => {
      this.dataSource.data.forEach((node, index) => node.site = sites[index]);
    })
  ).subscribe(
    site => {
      sites.push(site);
    },
    error => {
      // handle error
    }
  );
}
```

Now the 6000 requests will be done sequentially, so it'll be too slow.

#### Update: concurrent requests using [`mergeMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeMap)

As suggested by Will Alexander in the comments, you could use RxJS `mergeMap` operator to have concurrent requests. But I'd advise you to keep it less than 6 since most browsers have a hard limit on number of simultaneous requests to a unique domain.

So you could replace

```js
concatMap(request => of(request))
```

with

```js
mergeMap(request => of(request), null, 5)   // <-- 5 concurrent requests
```

Comment: I'd advise having the method return the Observable rather than subscribe to it. You could also use `mergeMap` with a concurrency limiting value to allow for multiple parallel requests.

Comment: @WillAlexander: I've updated the answer to include `mergeMap`, but returning the observable doesn't make any difference to me except structural changes. We could define the entire function in the service and expose only the final observable to the component, but it's up to the OP.

Comment: I hava an error : TS2345: Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObservableInput ' in line return from...

Comment: @pasgeek: I was wrongfully returning the `nodes` array instead of the `requests` array. I've modified the code.

Comment: thank you @MichaelD for the answer, but the result is not good, i got : Node = `{id: 2, name: "008", site: Observable, site_id: 5}`, the site property is an observable and not an object as i wanted

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```js
public getAllNodes() {
  return this.nodeService.getList().pipe(

    // emit all elements of the array separately
    map(nodes => from(nodes)),
    
    // subscribe to each Observable in turn
    // allow 5 concurrent requests
    mergeMap(node$ => node$, null, 5).pipe(

      // for each node, get the corresponding site, and emit the full object
      concatMap(
        node => this.siteService.getSiteById(node.site_id),
        (node, site) => { ...node, site })
    ),

    // when Observable completes, emit all emissions as an Array
    toArray()
  );
}
```

### Update: took into account fact that getList() returns Observables

Comment: node in mergeMap is an observable, so node.site_id causes an error

Comment: Oh your getList returns an array of Observables?

Comment: this getList method: public getList(): Observable<Nodes[]> { return this.http.get<Nodes[]>(URL); }

Comment: How about this?

Comment: Now i have this error in the mergeMap operator (node$ is unknown): TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 3, '(project: (value: unknown, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>, resultSelector: undefined, concurrent?: number): OperatorFunction<unknown, any>', gave the following error.     Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.

Comment: Do you understand the idea behind the approach here?